# Can we upload the next version of app previously developed in Ionic but now developed in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-play, app-store

Can we upload the next version written in React Native on the App Store and Play Store? The app is already live but developed in Ionic and having more than 18k users. I don't want to lose my active users. I want to upload an app with the same package name but written in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it does not differ than updating the app with the same technology.